# 3 Xbee Communictaion : A to B and B to C

Tags: xbee, zigbee

For a new project, I am developing a RTK system. Here, I have a device named Base which has to transmit its NMEA data to another device termed as Rover. For communication purpose I have used Xbee S2C Pro. 
The data received by Xbee of Base (termed as A) is being transmitted to Xbee of Rover(termed as B). That is communication from A to B takes place.

Now, I want to transmit the data from Rover to another device which is a computer. Also here I have used a Xbee (termed as C) for communication.

Xbee A = Router 1; Xbee B = Coordinator; Xbee C = Router 2;
Xbee A sends data to Xbee B and Xbee B sends data to Xbee A

The NMEA strings given to the Xbee A are as shown :
[image]

The data received on Xbee B is as shown :
[image]

No data is being received in Xbee C :
[image]

However, when I give data to Xbee B through the console window, it gets received by Xbee C 
[image]

Need a help for this scenario.

Comment: So, Xbee A = Base = Router 1, Xbee B = Rover = Coordinator, Xbee C = Router 2 = Computer? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Communication between Xbee A and B is good. But not being able communicate between Xbee B and Xbee C

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific protocol requirement here is a suggestion:

1. By using XCTU app from Digi, flash 802.15.4 firmware into all xbee modules.
2. Set NODE A as coordinator and others as ENDPOINT.
3. Set up a mesh network by channel settings.
4. Now set the NMEA source's (which is NODE A) destination address to broadcast.

When the system starts to work, both NODE B and NODE C will receive the NMEA data sent from NODE A.